# Is there any PhantomJS api.readPdf() equivalent function in Chrome/Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, chromium, puppeteer

I am newbie in NodeJs and Puppeteer.
I am in a process of upgrading an old PhantomJs pdf report generator. 
The Phantom workflow reads the PDF in the following way

```
api.readPdf(result.file)
                      .then(function(data) {
                                return({ page: result.page,
                                         file: result.file,
                                         data: data
                                       });
                            });
```

and downloads the Pdf using the .data of the result.

While using Puppeteer I was able to generate the Pdf using the following code sample.

```
async function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
(async ()=>{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    var paramData = completeParamData(reportParam);
    await page.goto(reportParam.templateUrl,{ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
    await page.emulateMedia('screen');
    await page.evaluate(doInjectParams, reportParam);
    await timeout(5000);
    var ts = new Date().getTime();
    await page.evaluate(() => { window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight); })
    await page.pdf({
        path:`mydoc_${ts}.pdf`,
        format: 'A4',
        printBackground:true
    });

    //**this data I dont want to fetch using the PhantomJS api**
    const data = await api.readPdf(`mydoc_${ts}.pdf`)
                  .then(function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            return data;
                        });
    await workflowDone(null,
        { data: data,
          filename: `mydoc_${ts}.pdf`,
          download: sanitize(`mydoc_${ts}.pdf`)});

    })();
```

The pdf generation is a success and my file is also getting downloaded, can you advise if there is an alternative to my api.readPdf() using puppeteer or some other api ?

Comment: No, I think that's out of the scope of puppeteer.

Comment: Do you want to get generated PDF bytes? Is this what `readPdf` does?

Comment: @slava Thank you, But I wanted to get the file bytes. I think using this will solve my problem   `var readFile = Q.denodeify(fs.readFile);
  return readFile(filename,
      { encoding: 'base64'
      });`

Comment: @SubhadipPal Why would you store PDF on the file system and after trying to read it? Per [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions) `page.pdf` return Promise which resolves with PDF buffer. As long as you have it, you may serve it to browser with content type `application/pdf`, do base64 encoding if you need it to use in data URL for example or what ever else you want to do, including saving into file.

Comment: @SlavaIvanov thank you will try your suggestion.